# Repeated measure design

Tags: repeated-measures, anova

Say I have two groups of people A and B. For both groups, I take repeated measurements of a certain variable C. Now, I would like to say something about the difference between the median value of C for A and B.

Anova considers just the mean between the groups so I wonder what's the right technique to use in this case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fortunately, the answer is simple! Just take the median of C for each person, and then run a T-test, or another two-group test, on the medians. While it sounds a bit strange, you are testing whether the mean median of group A is different than the mean median of group B for the variable C.

This analysis captures the between-person, as opposed to the within-person, effect of the grouping factor. This is similar to when laboratory scientists perform a chemical assay in triplicate and then use the mean of the triplicates, or the median in your case, and then continue with standard statistical analysis. It is a way to decrease analytical/technical variation.

Comment: In your specific example using means, how does it differ to a mixed design ANOVA? When would you choose one over the other?

Comment: For the example I give above, a mixed design would accomplish the same thing, but would also estimate the effect of the technical variation. Researchers are often more interested in the effect of treatment, but if you were interested in quantifying the effect of your technical error, than a mixed design would give you that information in addition. Mixed designs are meant when you are interested in the effect of the repeated sample e.g. the effect of time or a treatment X time interaction.